# microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: c#

I am implementing `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed` in my application to use with Azure Redis.

I've added the `startup.cs` code as per instructions:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnectionString");
                options.InstanceName = "NAME";
});
```

When other developers on the team based in the US run their application, everything works fine. When developers from another country run their app, they get this error:

[image: error]

Commenting out the code above allows the application to run.

Any idea what might be causing this? Firewall doesn't seem to be the issue in Azure Redis as they can access the Redis server from a different application.

I do have the following code that uses the cache

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    string jsonValue = _cache.GetString(key);

    if (jsonValue == null)
    {
        return default(T); // Key not found
    }

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonValue);
}
```

EDIT:

This is what I was told is in the event log

```
A worker process '10288' serving application pool 'AppName' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.
2:12
A worker process with pid '10288' that serves application pool 'AppName' has been determined to be unhealthy (see previous event log message), but because a debugger is attached to it, the Windows Process Activation Service will ignore the error.
2:12
A process serving application pool 'AppName' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '10288'.
```

Comment: Did you check "Event log" for error message?

Comment: Can you add exception and share the logs message?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan added what was in the logs